# Renaming functions and variables in an original theme

Tags: themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to create a theme, using a default WordPress theme as the initial point.

According to WordPress Codex, the recommended way to do that is to create a child theme.

Unfortunately, that approach may noticeably affect the performance of a site, because both themes have to be called before the site is actually displayed. WordPress tends to be fairly slow on quite a number of popular hosts, so slowing it down even further is not something I would want to do.

At the same time, coding a theme from scratch seems to be inefficient when an open source theme is close enough to the desired result to only require certain minor recoding.

**Question:** if I rename the theme in the main CSS file, there's still a lot of function callbacks and variables addressing the name of the old theme (for example, 'twentyeleven'). There has to be some central location where these are called from. What things do I need to rename, in addition to the theme name at the top of CSS file, to fully rename the entire theme an prevent it from being updated, should the original theme be updated by WordPress development theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions and callbacks of a theme are only being used if the theme is activated. So if you copy the 'twentyeleven' theme into a new folder & activate it, only those functions are loaded even if they have the same name(s) as the original theme. To answer your question (going with the 'twentyeleven' theme):

1. Copy the 'twentyeleven' theme folder and give it a unique name
2. Edit the file `style.css` in your freshly copied theme folder. Change the `Theme Name:`, `Theme URI:`, `Theme Author:`, `Description:` & `Version:` values to match your desired output.
3. Go to Appearance->Themes and activate your new theme

You have now a 'twentyeleven' clone, but completely independent of the original files. Any updates available for the 'twentyeleven' theme will not affect your theme (there will be no updates listed for your theme).

HTH

Comment: That's great, thank you. So, do I understand it correctly – if I copy a theme to a new folder, rename it the css, changing it from "twentyeleven" to "myrenamedtheme", and only then activate it – all the functions and callbacks will automatically rename themselves, and I will read 'myrenamedtheme' throughout the code wherever 'twentyeleven' used to be?

Comment: No. You would still have to rename all function names, variables, text domain etc., but you will not run into any PHP errors like 'x has already been defined in y' since 'myrenamedtheme' is now independent, i.e. not a child theme. You can rename all that with a  text editor like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Comment: So, basically, I just have to go through all the files and do search /  replace. Correct? And after I have done it, will the new theme still work?

Comment: Yes. If you do the search & replace correctly, the theme will work just fine. Check the ['Getting Started' section of the _s theme](https://github.com/automattic/_s), there it is documented how to properly do that.

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in [html5blank](http://html5blank.com), a boilerplate wordpress theme

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and useful. Unfortunately, this is not the answer to the question that I asked, but I will probably find that theme useful in the future at some point.

Comment: i tried converting a theme like you, got feed up with it. some themes are easier to modify code, hopefully you wont have any issues. maybe you could remove the hardcoded values and use constants, do everything you can to make it more flexible for you for future mods :)